# ATTiny84a and RFM12b issues

Tags: arduino, spi, attiny

Im trying to set up the attiny84a and the RFM12b with the Jeelib library for arduino. It works perfectly with the arduino but not with the ATTiny. We are 3 people that have tried to solve the problem tree days without luck.

We can easily upload the software to the tiny. no problem. Everything seems fine except that we cant send and receive data. We are currently debugging with a blinking diode on terminal 6 (PA7) and we are finishing with The init method, but it is as if we dont get any further than that.

Here is the drawings of the Arduino UNO drawings
[image: Arduino UNO RFM12B][image]

Here is the drawings of the ATTiny. Dont mind the wrong name of the tiny. Terminal 1 starts from upper right corner.

[image: ATtiny84a RFM12B][image]

We tried to switch the miso mosi wires(green) serval times. Tried with and without Slave Select (yellow) and a lot of other things.

My question is: Do we miss anything? And is the wiring ok on the picture?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need bypass caps on the ATtiny, across VCC/GND.  A 0.01uF to 0.1uF would be good.  jeelabs commented on the startup power requirements of the RF module.  It could be affecting the ATtiny: brownout, reset, brownout, etc.

You should show us your code.  -_-